# Create Objective-C literal object like NSString

Tags: objective-c, object, literals

I want to know if it's possible to create Objective-C literals like `NSString`, where instead of `[[Object alloc] init]`, and then assigning you can just assign a value to it, such as `@"A string"`.

Obviously `NSString` is an object because it has methods to manipulate the data in addition, so in theory there should be a way to do it yourself, but I'm not sure where to even go about finding stuff like this.

Comment: Question unclear. NSInteger is a primitive (it's a typedef for long int or similar). NSString is not; it's an object. What exactly is it that you want to do?

Comment: "you can just assign a value to it" But what value would you assign?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objective-C is C. The primitive (what I would call *scalar*) data types are all numbers and are completely defined by the language; you cannot add to them (though you can rename them using `typedef`. The corresponding literals, such as `1` and `"hello"`, are also part of C.

Similarly, literals like `@"howdy"` and `@[@"howdy"]`, though defined by Objective-C rather than C, are part of the language and you cannot change or add to them, as the literal syntax is built into the language.

Comment: Something like what you describe is possible in Swift, however, where you can make a type conform to one of the built-in `Literal` protocols and thus use a literal where an object of that type is expected. See http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_literal_convertibles for an example. This could be a reason for switching for Swift (or at least giving it a try).

Comment: I think you misinterpret the question. I don't want to change the way the literals are formated or anything like that, I want an object to be able to be assigned a primitive such as an int or a string or an array if possible on definition such as MyNewClass *class = @"Hello" or something similar

Comment: I think you misinterpret the answer. I'm telling you you can't do that, because `@"Hello"` _is_ a string literal and cannot go where a MyNewClass is expected. But you _can_ do something like this in Swift. There, you've made me say my answer twice, well done. :)

Comment: Sorry for my confusion. I misread your answer. I will accept this as the answer to my question. A shame that you cant do that in objective c though. I don't really want to go to swift just yet but I will be sure to check this out when I get there